# Дополнительные директории

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, можно ли в Areas (области) добавить дополнительные директории? Т.е. в Areas добавляю папку, а в неё размещаю уже область.

Когда я так делаю, у меня ниче не работает. Может есть какие-нибудь способы настройки роутинга или это невозможно впринципе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно, но в RouteConfig придется менять паттерн...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620178/asp-net-mvc-routing-and-areas

http://habrahabr.ru/post/176021/